# How to add progress status of a downloading file in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, progress-information

I want to show (regularly update) my download/upload progress of a file on my telegram bot.

I'm using aria2 for downloading and rclone for uploading. And all I'm using is bash/shell script.

```
aria2c $url | text=$(grep '%') | curl -s "https://api.telegram.org/bot${TG_TOKEN}/editMessageText" --data "message_id=${msg_id}&text=DOWNLOADED-${text}&chat_id=${ch_id}&parse_mode=HTML&disable_web_page_preview=True"
```

Also I want it to update after every 5 seconds.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your post to indicate what you already tried and where you faced problems. That way you can avoid getting answers that you already know won't work.

Comment: Actually I'm getting blank output after trying to grep percentage, might be something wrong with regex

Comment: ```[#978650 1.5GiB/1.8GiB(81%) CN:1 DL:89MiB ETA:3s]           [#978650 1.6GiB/1.8GiB(87%) CN:1 DL:91MiB ETA:2s]           [#978650 1.7GiB/1.8GiB(92%) CN:1 DL:96MiB ETA:1s]           [#978650 1.8GiB/1.8GiB(97%) CN:1 DL:100MiB]``` I tried to store the output in a file and output was something like this. Can you help me to get correct regex with grep to get download percentage ?

Comment: When asked for clarifications, please don't respond in comments, but edit your post to include the requested information. Reading through the comments is rather painful, and comments are subject to removal without notice by moderators.

Answer (score 0):

```
aria2c $url --summary-interval=5
```

source: [advanced options](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#advanced-options)

Comment: I also want to filter /grep  Download percentage from it and use curl to send updated message. Can you help me with an example.